# Populate a label on multiple pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a drop down list that populates a set of data from a calculation. There are multiple pages in my asp.net site that I want to show a label with the current data from the dropdownlist on my main page. Here is my code...

```
''' In the page load'''
Dim Val As Double
    If Date.Now.Month = 10 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 11 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 12 Then
        Val = Date.Now.Year
    Else
        Val = Date.Now.Year - 1
    End If

    For i = Val To 1996 Step -1
        dropdownlist1.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub

'''function in a seperate class'''
Function GetDates(currentYear As Double) As String
    Dim x As String
    Return x
End Function

'''In the selected index event of the drop down (populates years ie. 2011, 2010, 2009)'''
Dim x As String = class1.GetDates(dropdownlist1.Text)

'''In the other pages load events''' 
Dim x As String = class1.GetDates(label1.Text)
```

This above line of code is what I want to populate with the current year (ie. 2011, 2010, 2009) Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give more details on your problem? Does drop down populate some DataSet? Or do you want to select a year in drop-down on your main page and see this year on all the other pages?

Comment: A little of both, bare with me please I am new to this site. The drop down populates a dataset related to the current fiscal year starting at year 1996, I want when a user selects a year (ie. 2007) from the main page, to have a label that shows the current selected value on each of the other 9 pages. Does this make sense?

Comment: @developthestars - Hi, is it possible for you to put the label at master page? I think it will work. Access master page label to fill and to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a perfect fit for a user control. You can consolidate the functionality of the label display into one class. Any subsequent changes to the display/functionality will only have to be coded once. Also, by allowing each page to decide if/what it will display, this approach will give you the flexibility that will inevitably be needed in the future.

By creating a class, like SettingsManager below, you can access the Year value via a single point from anywhere in the site without having to know the details of how/where it is stored.

```
public class SettingsManager
{
    public string Year
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SettingsManager:Year"] == null)
            {
                //set default value
            }
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["SettingsManager:Year"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["SettingsManager:Year"] = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Your user control will have a simple label (`lblYear`) and the following code in the code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.lblYear.Text = new SettingsManager().Year;
        }
    }
```

Now, for each page you want to display this in, just register the user control:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagName="YearControlUC" TagPrefix="SO" %>
```

And insert an instance of the the control anywhere on the page:

```
<SO:YearControlUC runat="server" />
```

And voila, a simple, easy to maintain solution.

EDIT:

'''In the selected index event of the drop down (populates years ie. 2011, 2010, 2009)'''

```
Dim x As String = class1.GetDates(dropdownlist1.Text)
```

change to

```
New SettingsManager().Year = dropdownlist1.Text
```

Comment: This worked for an instance of the current year, how do I tie it to populate what the user selects from my dropdown on my main page?

Comment: Im having issue making my defualt value that I set in my get/if statement come out right... Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want the default value to be? Can you provide pseudo-code as an example?

Comment: I actually figured it out, I was pulling the default value from my dropdown on main page and could not get it to connect. I have do so now. Thanks Shai for all your help!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your main page save your selected year to session:

```
Session.Add("myYear", dropdownlist1.SelectedValue)
```

In other pages:

```
Function GetDates(currentYear As Double) As String 
    Dim x As String 
    x = Session("myYear")
    Return x 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should look into creating a masterpage with your dropdown and create 9 pages based on that masterpage.

Comment: @Dim thanks for your help however, the label still won't populate. I am going to tie it to my master and see if Pleun and Mohan suggestion will work